# JAVA - Рассчитать среднее арифметическое массива случайных чисел

Tags: java

Написал код, суть которого, рассчитать среднее арифметическое массива случайных чисел. Но он не работает и я не могу понять почему.

```
package homework30.pkg09.pkg17;

import java.util.Random;

public class task5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int mas[] = new int[7];
        float count = 5;
        float average = 0;
        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            mas[i] = rand.nextInt(6);
            System.out.print(mas[i]);
            sum += mas[i];
            average = sum/count;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Сумма чисел " + sum + " ,а среднее равно= "+average);
    }

}
```

Comment: А почему, собственно, он должен работать?

Comment: Как бы Вам сказать, он должен работать, как по мне. Но он не работает. Именно по этому я задал данный вопрос, чтобы понять что в нем не так.

Comment: Вы перетираете каждый раз значения переменных. Представьте, если число 1 сгенерируется два раза. У вас в а будет лежать 1, хотя должно быть 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял надо что-то типо такого?

```
    Random rand = new Random();

    int count = 5;
    int sum = 0;

    int mas[] = new int[7];
    for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        mas[i] = rand.nextInt(6);
        System.out.println("Число - " + mas[i]);
        sum += mas[i];
    }

    System.out.println("Среднее - " + (sum/count));
```

Comment: Не совсем, потому что мне необходимо сделать это с массивом

Comment: @BattleMonster поправил.

Comment: В общем, с помощью Вашего кода сделал следующее (смотрите код в начале)

Comment: @BattleMonster глупая запись `average = sum/count;`. При каждой итерации это значение будет изменяться. Сделать можно так: 
`System.out.print("Сумма чисел " + sum + " ,а среднее равно= "+sum/count);` и убрать из цикла `average = sum/count;` = суть та же.

Comment: `(sum/count)` - int на int поделил...

Comment: @Qwertiy господи, проблема. `(double) sum/count`.

Answer (score 4):

А можно сделать красиво через стримы

```
new Random().ints(10).average()
```

где 10 - это количество рандомных интов

Answer (score 3):

Можно было бы заменить все куски вида `a = 1;` на `a += 1`, но вообще весь этот код - какая-то жесть. Среднее арифметическое - это сумма всех элементов, делённая на их количество. Причём перед делением надо сумму привести к `double`, чтобы деление не было целочисленным.